# How do I block Windows access to Bing search?

Tags: windows-8.1, bing

I'd like to block, NOT disable access to Bing's Internet search via Windows search. I've tried with OpenDNS and while it blocks the Bing domain via a browser, access to "search the web" via Windows search isn't blocked. Is there anyway to block this rather than disable it?

I find it immensely frustrating that Windows implemented this as a permanent feature at the OS level as the computers I have require Internet access but I need them safe for tech savvy kids.

Comment: The only way this is possible is if you disable [Windows Smart Search](https://www.technorms.com/31671/disable-bing-search-results-windows-8-1) altogether.  You can also block `https://www.windowssearch.com` which is the domain `Windows Smart Search` uses.  Although, blocking it without disabling it first, will result in weird behavior.  I would submit an answer, but I suspect blocking the domain, really will result in behavior that you will find undesirable.  So I personally would find an answer like that unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks. Why would blocking the domain cause problematic results? I also don't understand why blocking Bing from being accessed at all by one's internet isn't possible at the router/DNS level.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that we can only disable Windows access to Bing search instead of blocking it.

Based on your description, we do not want to disable Windows access to Bing search, so we can customize search with Bing in Windows 8.1 according to the following link. We can customize the following three points:

Customize How Bing Search is Used in Windows 8.1

Filter Adult Content in Windows 8.1 Search Results

Configure Search with Bing over Metered Connections

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-customize-or-disable-search-bing-windows-81

Comment: Disabling is precisely what I don't want as it's incredibly easy to re-enable. Microsoft didn't seem to bother adding password lock options. Why is it not possible to bloock any and all access to the Bing search domain through one's router?